# Attempt to de-reference a null object - Wrapper list

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to get the records from wrapperList.

Attempt to de-reference a null object Error is in expression '{!next}' in page retailcampaignsegmentation:

> Class.RetailCampaignSegmentationController.next: line 897, column 1

The Following is my vf page code :

```
<div style="margin:6px;">Records: {!IF(accounts == null, 0, accounts.size)}</div>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" value="NextPage" reRender="accounts"/>
            <apex:outputPanel id="accounts">
                <apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapAccountListDisplay}" var="wrapAcc" rendered="{!wrapAccountList != null && wrapAccountList.size > 0}">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <c:selectAllChkBox />
                        </apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapAcc.isSelected}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="{!$ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name.Label}">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!wrapAcc.acc.Id}">{!wrapAcc.acc.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!wrapAcc.acc.PersonHomePhone}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wrapAcc.acc.PersonMobilePhone}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wrapAcc.acc.Phone}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!wrapAcc.acc.PersonEmail}"/>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>
```

The following is my apex code :

```
 public transient List<wrapperAccount> wrapAccountList{get;set;}
public List<wrapperAccount> wrapAccountListDisplay {set;get;}

public void loadWrapAccounts()
{
    wrapAccountList = new  List<wrapperAccount>();
    wrapAccountListDisplay = new  List<wrapperAccount>(); 
    if(accounts != null){     
        for(Account a : accounts){
            wrapperAccount wrapAcc = new wrapperAccount();
            wrapAcc.acc = a;               // Holding Account
            wrapAcc.isSelected = false;    // Used as Checkbox in vf page, default is not selected
            wrapAccountList.add(wrapAcc);   
        }
        for(Integer i=count;i<count+recordsPerPage;i++){
            wrapAccountListDisplay.add(wrapAccountList[i]);    
        }
    }
} 

public void next(){
    wrapAccountListDisplay = new List<wrapperAccount>();
    count += recordsPerPage;
    for(Integer i=count; i<count+recordsPerPage;i++){
        wrapAccountListDisplay.add(wrapAccountList[i]);//This is my line number 897
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put exact line where you are getting exception, its hard to read, as you have posted code without Line Number!

Comment: In the next method I'ready mentioned the line for reference : wrapAccountListDisplay.add(wrapAccountList[i]);//This is my line number 897

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only value that can be `null` at the line you indicate is `wrapAccountList` and that is entirely possible even if it was initialised earlier because it is marked as [transient](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm) and so will not have its value restored when the `next` action runs. A quick fix is probably to remove the `transient`, but other restructuring of the controller may make more sense.

Comment: But I'm getting more than 6,000 records and I'm getting the view state error, that's why I used 'transient'

Comment: @Lokesh Yes, hence my comment that you may need to restructure the controller in some other way such as requerying.

Comment: Is there any other possibility to resolve this.

Comment: @Lokesh Hard to say: suggest you Google for pagination in controllers and look for a pattern that will fit well with your 900+ existing lines of code.